# How to populate a linked list from mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, linked-list

I have a set of data in a database table. Each row of the table contains two values. The first value is a name, and the second value is equal to the first value of some other row.

How can I create a linked list to traverse like this? I need to go from one row to the next based on the value in the second field.

Comment: And you want the whole table in memory?

Comment: Are the references strictly 1:1, or could there be two rows whose second value is the same?

Comment: The references are 1:1 only.